# Как передать из родительского в дочерний компонент метод в Composition Api?

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать метод в дочерний компонент?
Например:

```
//parent
<Component
:number="number"
@change="change"/>

const number = ref(0);
const change = (step) => {
  number += step;
};

//child
<p>{{ props.number}}</p>
<button @click="change(+1)">click</button>

const props = defineProps({
  number: Number,
});

const emits = defineEmits(['change']);
```

При клике выдаёт ошибку, что change не является функцией

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Provide/Inject](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#composition-api-dependency-injection)
как для переменных, так и для методов.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Большое спасибо